# Rsync -l flag is not working as expected for simlink

Tags: symlink, rsync

I have a parition A and parition B of flash memonry. I want to copy the content of partition A to partition B. In that some `simlinks/softlinks` are also present, so why copying content of `[/etc/os-release-> ../usr/bin/os-release]` to `[mnt/p5/etc/os-release-> ../usr/bin/os-release]`. It is not syncing for this particular os-release files for A(source) and B(Destination).

It is working for `-L` flag but after sync it deltes the symlink but I want to keep symlink pointing to same directory as it was pointing before sync.